# Store elements in comma separated txt file in to single variables (java)

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains values such as

> [GetLeagueStandingsResultDto(team=Celtic, teamId=54, played=28, playedAtHome=14, playedAway=14, won=19, draw=7, lost=2, numberOfShots=691, yellowCards=32, redCards=1, goalsFor=56, goalsAgainst=18, goalDifference=38, points=64, leagueName=null, season=null, id=54),
>
> GetLeagueStandingsResultDto(team=Rangers, teamId=49, played=29, playedAtHome=14, playedAway=15, won=18, draw=4, lost=7, numberOfShots=507, yellowCards=46, redCards=4, goalsFor=59, goalsAgainst=32, goalDifference=27, points=58, leagueName=null, season=null, id=49)

what i want to do is grab each teams `goalsFor` number and put them into separate variables.

Could anybody push me in the right direction?

Comment: read every line as a String, use the split method with , as token, and map your Strings after a new split call with = as token.

Comment: If you only need the `goalsFor` number you just do a simple string index and then get the number after the `=` or use a regex to extract the number directly: `goalsFor=(\d+)`

Comment: @xander he also needs the team name, so `.*team=([^,]+).*goalsFor=(\d+),.*`

Comment: @xander thanks for your reply :) What exactly do you mean by string index? So far I have 
FileReader fr = new FileReader("table.txt");
            `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String result="";
            result=reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(result);`

which currently just reads the whole file

EDIT: I created a new string to contain "goalsFor" and then printed out the result.IndexOf(goalsFor) and got 167... I'm guessing this is the items position in the text file?

Comment: @Saterz yes something like that is what I meant, you get the index of the name and then read the value after that, maybe you can figure something out yourself, just try it yourself to learn more about the String methods The official java doc is always a good start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @daniu I have used the expression you provided, as such:

 .*team=(Celtic).*goalsFor=(\d+),.*

However this only returns "celitc" and not how many goals they scored, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get the values that you need from the string is to use a regex pattern.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "table.txt";
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = "";

        try {

            if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                // Match and capture the values we are looking for
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("team=(\\w+),[\\w\\s,=]+goalsFor=(\\d+),");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

                while (matcher.find()) {

                    // Output the results, you could store them in a 
                    // variable instead
                    System.out.println("Team name: " + matcher.group(1) +
                        ". Goals for: " + matcher.group(2));
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The regex pattern `team=(\\w+),[\\w\\s,=]+goalsFor=(\\d+),` does the following:

1. `team=(\\w+),` matches exactly `team=` followed by matching any alphanumeric characters `\w` one or more times `+`, in a capturing group, then it matches the character `,`
2. `[\\w\\s,=]+` matches any alphanumeric character `\w`, any whitespace `\s` the `,` character or the `=` character, one or more times because of the quantifier `+`, it will stop matching when it finds the character `)`. You could substitute for `[^\)]+`, match anything but a `)` character.
3. Then the engine will look backwards to try and find a match for `goalsFor=(\\d+),`, this pattern matches exactly the characters `goalsFor=` followed by one or more digits, in a capturing group, followed by a, not necessary, `,` character.

This pattern will result in one match per *team*, with the name of the team stored in the first capturing group and the number of goals for stored in the second capturing group.

If you want to learn more about regex, or experiment by yourself, there is good documentation online, pretty much every programming language has a section in their documentation dedicated to regular expressions, and also a few *playgrounds* that are convenient and fun to use, I use [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) but there must be hundreds.

Comment: I should specify the text file is all one line, at the moment this regex pattern gets the first teams name, and the last teams goalsFor 
Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: @Saterz see the update, it works for a single line input formatted like the one in your example. It would fail if the team's data wasn't enclosed on `()`

Comment: Thank you so much! would it be possible to further explain the regex pattern so that i could understand what its doing easier? This is perfect though thank you.

Comment: @Saterz I updated the answer with an explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to read each line and analyse it with a regex, eg

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("team=([^,]*)[^)]*goalsFor=(\\d+),");

try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(yourData)) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.printf("Team: %s; Goals: %s", m.group(1), m.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've been very helpful to me so far, thank you :)

However I think the regex expression is a little off, at the moment it only gets the team and goalsFor for the last team in the txt file. I have to add another \ to goalsFor=(\d+) or i get an "illegal escape character"

Comment: @Saterz oops on the double backslash, corrected. It sounds like the file contains a single line? Adjusted the answer for that as well (I think).

Comment: yeah the API Im using prints all the data on to a single line

Comment: still seems to only get first team name, and last teams goasFor... @daniu